# checking if a program is upgradeable

Tags: account, account-data

I am trying to work out how to get some meta data for Solana programs.

I can see on sol explorer etc that it knows whether a program is upgradeable, and if it is, who the upgrade authority is, but I can't find out how to actually get this information myself.

Just calling 'get_account_info' on the program account just reveals that it is executable and is owned by the BPFLoaderUpgradeable regardless of whether it is actually upgradeable anymore.  Is this information somehow encoded in the data contained in the program account?  If so, how should I extract it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you encountered a program owned by BPFLoaderUpgradeable that _wasn't_ upgradeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use Solscan's public API to programatically fetch this information.

Let's say you want to get details of this program account - So1endDq2YkqhipRh3WViPa8hdiSpxWy6z3Z6tMCpAo

You can do it via this curl request.

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://public-api-test.solscan.io/account/So1endDq2YkqhipRh3WViPa8hdiSpxWy6z3Z6tMCpAo' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

and the response would look like this. programInfo contains upgradeAuthority.

```
{
  "lamports": 1141440,
  "ownerProgram": "BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111",
  "type": "program",
  "rentEpoch": 211,
  "executable": true,
  "account": "So1endDq2YkqhipRh3WViPa8hdiSpxWy6z3Z6tMCpAo",
  "programInfo": {
    "programData": "DMCvGv1fS5rMcAvEDPDDBawPqbDRSzJh2Bo6qXCmgJkR",
    "upgradeable": true,
    "upgradeAuthority": "2Fwvr3MKhHhqakgjjEWcpWZZabbRCetHjukHi1zfKxjk",
    "deployedSlot": 151004996,
    "anchorVerify": "unverified",
    "anchorVerifyInfo": null
  }
}
```

It seems like you can decode the same information from programData when you call accountInfo. Need to dig into it though.

Comment: is this only for apps on the main-net?  I couldn't see how to specify the network.